# Showing that a probability is Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $a\in(0,1)$, $P,P_1,P_2$ probability measures on $\mathbb{N}$ which satisfy the equation $$P_1(\{k\})P_2(\{n-k\})=\binom{n}{k}a^k(1-a)^{n-k}P(\{n\})$$ for every $n,k\in\mathbb{N}, k\leq n.$ Show that  $P,P_1,P_2$ have Poisson distribution. Can you give me some ideas on how to do it? I don't know even where to start.

Comment: khan academy has a great video on it

Comment: take the limit as n approaches infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that your set of natural numbers includes zero, i.e., $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \cdots\}$. Also we write $p_1(k) = P_1(\{k\})$ and similarly for $P_2$ and $P$ for convenience.

First, plugging $k = n$ and $k = 0$ respectively gives

$$ p_1(n)p_2(0) = a^n p(n), \qquad p_1(0)p_2(n) = (1-a)^n p(n). $$

This in particular shows that $p_1(0)$ and $p_2(0)$ are non-zero, for otherwise $p$ is identically zero and $P$ cannot be a probability measure. Plugging this back to eliminate $p_1$ and $p_2$, we get

$$ \binom{n}{k}p(n)p(0) = p(k)p(n-k). $$

Now let $\lambda = p(1)/p(0)$. Then plugging $k = 1$ above shows that

$$ p(n) = \frac{\lambda}{n} p(n-1)$$

holds. Solving this recursive formula is straightforward, giving

$$ p(n) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}p(0). $$

Since $P$ is a probability measure, the constraint $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p(n) = 1$ forces $p(0) = e^{-\lambda}$, showing that $P$ has a Poisson distribution.